# How to properly revert from botched merges in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Sometimes a merge will cause the manual diff tool (in my case KDiff) to open, and sometimes it's not possible to resolve the merge properly manually.  If I close the diff tool without saving, then I get something like

```
1 files unresolved

use 'hg resolve' to retry unresolved file merges or 'hg update -C .' to abandon
```

I'm not really sure what state my workspace is in at this point.

**Is there any easy way after this happens to get back to the state I was in before I issued hg merge?**

Comment: You can revert the recent merge using `hg update -C -r .` But be informed that it will also remove any uncommitted changes.

Comment: @Mubin - I would have to specify a revision number after `-r` I suppose? (how to know what revision # to put here?)

Comment: the `.` after `-r` refers to last revision number.

Comment: Ah, great, thank you.  If you add as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revert the recent merge using `hg update -C -r .` But be informed that it will also remove any uncommitted changes.

The `.` after `-r` refers to last revision number.